# Using SwiftUI, how do I make one Toggle change the state of another Toggle?

Tags: swift, toggle, swiftui

I would like to have three SwiftUI Toggles and have them so that if one is on, the other two are off.

The old way of doing something like this using UIKit was didSet{}, which is not the correct way with SwiftUI. I don't know if it is neccessary to delve into Combine in order to solve this problem which, on the surface, seems like it should be simple.

```swift
import SwiftUI

// Mutually exclusive toggle switches: when one toggle is on, the other two should be off. This is a start, where to go from here?

struct Junk: View {

    @State private var isOn1:Bool = true
    @State private var isOn2:Bool = false
    @State private var isOn3:Bool = false

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            Toggle("T1", isOn: $isOn1)
            Toggle("T2", isOn: $isOn2)
            Toggle("T3", isOn: $isOn3)
        }
    }
}

struct Junk_Previews: PreviewProvider
{
    static var previews: some View
    {
        Junk()
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, first, why Isn't the "`UIKit`" way the right way? Maybe it is - using `ObservableObject` instead of *three* `@State` variables. (Please note, I'm *not* saying this is correct, just saying if you have three variables dependent on each - that's your posted code - *and* they are not local to the `View`, then why *aren't* you using `ObservableObject`? To be honest, I think *that's* the "correct SwiftUI way" - it separates the UI from the model, it moves the logic correctly to where it should be, and until you post more code? I need to hear why it *isn't* correct.

Comment: I said the UIKit way was to use didSet, which is not what you suggested. You suggested ObservableObject which is a part of the Combine framework. Thanks.

Comment: Except that that means using `willSet`. Again, IMHO your issue is with your example - which likely is simplified (that makes a god question) but obscures your intent - do you really need three local `Bools`? Wouldn't they work better in a model using an `ObservableObject`? And once you do that, what's wrong with `Swift` code such as `willSet` and `didSet`?

Comment: I'm new to SwiftUI and Combine. When I orginally asked this question, I assumed that willSet/didSet would have been obsoleted by something like a trailing closure to Toggle that would allow us to perform an action on state change.

Comment: We are all new to SwiftUI & Combine. (Personally, even with 35 years in IT and 5 with UIKit, this while thing - and a hobby for me - is really, um, raw!) My criticism? Beta 3, four weeks after WWDC. `PresentationButton` is now `PresentationLink`. Cool. 2 weeks later (and beta 4)? It's all obsoleted. For you? `BindingObject` became `ObservableObject` in beta 4 - and along with that, the protocol *requirements* changed from `didSet` to `willSet`. But `didSet` still works! The underlying structure - `Combine` - is still there (and thankfully open-source).

Comment: So, maybe the correct approach (for me) is to ask this - if you had three `Bool` values needed for your `UIKit` app and they needed to work together, how would you design it - in `UIKit`? A singleton? Something local to one `UIViewController`? Maybe a Framework target? That really matters, because in most - really all but one case (the local one) - the `Swiftui` answer is actually to use `Combine`. (Two months ago I commented quite a few times on here about a "paradigm change". This is the first time in weeks I'm doing that.)

Answer (score 23):

Since I don't know hte challenges of your design, I won't go into wether it is the right approach or not (unless that is your question). However, to achieve what you asked for, you can use an intermediary binding:

```swift
struct Junk: View {

    @State private var isOn1:Bool = true
    @State private var isOn2:Bool = false
    @State private var isOn3:Bool = false

    var body: some View
    {
        let on1 = Binding<Bool>(get: { self.isOn1 }, set: { self.isOn1 = $0; self.isOn2 = false; self.isOn3 = false })
        let on2 = Binding<Bool>(get: { self.isOn2 }, set: { self.isOn1 = false; self.isOn2 = $0; self.isOn3 = false })
        let on3 = Binding<Bool>(get: { self.isOn3 }, set: { self.isOn1 = false; self.isOn2 = false; self.isOn3 = $0 })        

        return VStack
            {
                Toggle("T1", isOn: on1)
                Toggle("T2", isOn: on2)
                Toggle("T3", isOn: on3)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you kontiki. It appears that using an intermediary binding is the best way to solve this problem, though it could also be solved with an ObservableObject. However, an ObservableObject would take more code and not have any benefits over this solution.

Comment: @kontiki This really solves a lot of problems I have encountered using SwiftUI. Thank you very much!

Comment: @kontiki fantastic solution that deserves more upvotes. In a lot of situations, an ObservableObject and Published setup is too bloated. Worked for me.

Comment: When I add the binding to body, I get the following build error:  
"Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type"

Comment: A delightful hack.

Answer (score 1):

This thread is pretty old, but I came across it while trying to solve this very same question. I did manage to solve it on my own using the .onChange modifier.  I'm pretty new to development, but I think this fairly graceful.  My situation is only with two toggles, but it should work for three as well.

```
struct SettingsView: View {

    @State var showFullArray = true
    @State var showHalfArray = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Toggle("Show Full Array", isOn: $showFullArray)
                .onChange(of: showFullArray) { newValue in
                    showHalfArray = !newValue
                }
            Toggle("Show Half Array", isOn: $showHalfArray)
                .onChange(of: showHalfArray) { newValue in
                    showFullArray = !newValue
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add "@State" to the declarations of showFullArray and showHalfArray to make it work.

Comment: True.  Thanks for catching that.